ID Increment that sticks to the row/item u added it with even when filtered or when adding/removing Items
So i have this Excel for a game i've been playing. And i have this ID system to calculate the different multipliers with de different upgraders, sellers and droppers. But the thing is when i filter the upgraders for example from A - Z to highest to lowest multiplier. The ID's get reset and says 1, 2, 3 ,4 ,5 ,... instead of like 10, 2, 9, 6,... I've looked online a lot but i can't find any solution. I'VE EVEN USED CHATGPT got close but then everything got reset when adding a new item when sort thru eachother (the ID's)
https://imgur.com/a/iUNrT2x   -   Filtered on raarity highest to lowest
https://imgur.com/a/QqHI3rt   -   Filtered on highest multiplier
I have added an image to give you an example on how it looks. This is the same for the other 2 aswell.
I have tried different formulas. I also tried VBA code chatgpt made me (cuz idk how to code vba)
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim idCol As ListColumn
    Dim newRow As ListRow
    
    ' Replace "TbDroppers" with your actual table name and "Droppers" with your actual sheet name
    Set tbl = Me.ListObjects("TbDroppers")
    
    ' Ensure IDs column exists and retrieve its reference
    If tbl.ListColumns.Count < 2 Then
        Set idCol = tbl.ListColumns.Add
        idCol.Name = "ID"
    Else
        Set idCol = tbl.ListColumns(1)
    End If
    
    ' Check if a new row was added
    If Not Intersect(Target, tbl.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Set newRow = Intersect(Target, tbl.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange).Rows(1)
        
        ' Assign ID only if it's a new row (ID is blank)
        If IsEmpty(newRow.Cells(1, idCol.Index)) Then
            newRow.Cells(1, idCol.Index).Value = tbl.ListRows.Count
        End If
        
        ' Loop through all rows to ensure IDs are sequential
        For i = 1 To tbl.ListRows.Count
            tbl.ListRows(i).Range.Cells(1, idCol.Index).Value = i
        Next i
        
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub

This was the final code gpt gave me.
